# Change UIBarButtonItem color when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm using images for `UIBarButtonItem` which are pure white and transparent. How can I change the tint color when the user selects an item? Is there any method which tells me what button is selected inside a `UIToolBar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily change the `tintColor` of your `UIBarButtonItem` when the user taps it like so:

```
@IBAction func myToolBarButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    myToolBarButton.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

You may want to use a [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/) instead if the user can only select one button at a time. A `UITabBar` will change the `tintColor` of the button that is selected and then change the button back to its default color when you select another button.

If you keep the `UIToolbar` you will have to handle the color changes yourself.